# Angular 1.6.x , how to render component tag from current component to html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to call already registered angular component(another) from a current component file to HTML but in HTML it's reading as String.

The code below, is im trying out in component file,

```
$scope.component = "<complaint-create-component></complaint-create-component>;
```

I tried ng-bind-HTML expression to call but that also reading as String. if I use this component name `(<complaint-create-component></complaint-create-component>)` directly into HTML file it's working fine(As expected).

Presently I'm using angular 1.6 version.

Please help me out.

Comment: With [`$compile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262450/when-using-compile-on-component-why-is-the-scope-passed-through-parent)

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Try use `$sce.trustAsHtml`:

```
$scope.component= $sce.trustAsHtml("<complaint-create-component></complaint-create-component>");
```